# How to find element's xpath in chrome for selenium testing

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

When I inspected my page in chrome, I get this:

```
<input class="form-control form-text required" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value="" size="60" maxlength="60" data-original-title="Enter your username.">
```

## 1.

I right clicked on this code and selected Copy > Xpath. I got this:

```
//*[@id="edit-name"]
```

I created a variable:

```
final By userNameField = By.xpath ("//*[@id="edit-name"]");
```

I get syntax error.

## 2.

Then I tried this by id

```
public void enterUserName(){
driver.findElement(By.id("edit-name")).sendKeys("admin"); 
System.out.println("User name is entered");
}
```

It entered the user name just fine. How do I find the correct xpath in chrome so I can create a variable like I tried in step 1?

Comment: If you have `double-quotes` inside `double-quotes`, you need to either escape the inside `double-quotes` or just use `single-quotes`. You have to use "\" to escape the inside `double-quotes` if you were to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`final By userNameField = By.xpath ("//*[@id="edit-name"]");`

You've got double quotes inside your quotes.
change to:

`final By userNameField = By.xpath ("//*[@id='edit-name']");`